# How get references on <include> elements from code?

Tags: android

How can I get reference to `<include>` elements(Can I get reference by id to an element in layout that I add through `<include>` tag)?

Comment: you are probably going to have to elaborate or give an example of what you mean by adding through the <include> tag. You can find references to your xml views with findViewById(R.id.yourViewId);

Answer (score 1):

Get reference by using `findViewById`

***See the following Example***

**RelativeLayoutTesting.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class RelativeLayoutTesting extends Activity {

    android.widget.RelativeLayout currentView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        // set the relative layout as our view 
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
        et.setText("My Edit");
    }
}
```

**main1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/alpha"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#ff0000" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/edittext_layoout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**edittext_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just do as allways:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textViewFromIncludedLayout );
```

Just make sure that you don't have identical ID's - e.g. a `myTextView` in the main layout and then you include a layout in the main layout that also has a `myTextView`.

Answer (score 0):

You get references using

```
findViewById
```

Whatever way you used to add the view on your activity, it doesn't matter: `findViewById` will try to find a reference for the given id on **what is currently displayed on screen** (even if hidden or gone, the important is it needs to have been inflated in some way).